# Aggregations using Spark Data Frames in Java for Large Data

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I have around 6-8TB of data each in a sharded table with 5 partitions. This table is in HBase. I have built a Java based spark job that reads data from this table and performs some aggregations to get aggregates for a set of columns treated as key and then finally writes back the results into another table. Initially, i tried with spark map and foreach api, and performed aggregations in memory using data structures such HashMap. This was finally upserted into table using jdbc connection. However, the performance was really bad and the job never completed. Then, wrote a new job using DataFrames. I am pulling the data using HBaseRDD API and converting it into dataframe, then i perform groupBY and aggregations and finally saving the results using

" finalDF.save("org.apache.phoenix.spark", SaveMode.Overwrite, output_conf);"

This also was taking time,so i divided the task based on a key range and processed a range (say 1 million users) at a time with repartitioning the data by 2001 to ensure high compression.

```
DataFrame sessionDF = new PhoenixRDD(sqlContext.sparkContext(),inputTable,JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(cols).asScala().toSeq(),Option.apply(filter),Option.apply(source),hconf).toDataFrame(sqlContext).repartition(partitions);
```

The spark job properties used are as below:

```
--spark.app.name test
--spark.master yarn
--spark.deploy.mode cluster
--spark.driver.cores 2
--spark.driver.memory 4G
--spark.executor.instances 8
--spark.executor.cores 2
--spark.executor.memory 16G
--spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 6000000
--spark.default.parallelism 2001
--spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 4096
--spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms 6000000
--spark.network.timeout 6000000
--spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
--spark.shuffle.io.retryWait 60s
--spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries 10
```

The problem is that this job takes around 8-10hrs to process just one million users which is close to 1TB of data and after that it usually start giving "org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 1" and takes another 5-6hrs to finish. I tried increasing executors and memory, but still end up with this issue somewhere during the run and its getting difficult to process this whole data.

Can someone please advise how can i improve the processing of this job?
Please let me know if you need any further information.

Here is the cut-down version of aggregation step:

```
finalDF
    .select(col("OID"), col("CID")
        , col(“P”))
    .groupBy(col("OID")
        , col("CID”))
    .agg(sum(when(col("P").equalTo(lit("sd")).or(col("P").equalTo(lit("hd"))), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).alias("P"));
```

There are many more fields and other aggregations as part of this statement.

Comment: There's also spark.sql.shuffle.partitions parameter you can try. It would be good to know the times for following stages. 1) Load data from hbase. 2). Compute group aggregate. 3). Save data back to hbase. If you run each stage and save to temporary file on HDFS that will give you an idea of which part is it slow.

Comment: Also the web ui and history ui will show you break downs of tasks etc and timings. Any errors from executors require data to be recomputed and possibly even pulled from hbase again. You can persist() dataframe at key points. Check StorageLevel enum for possible values, but things like DISK_2 saves 2 copies for redundancy in case one executor dies.

Comment: Also try moving pre-processing some columns. if P column contains long strings, there's a lot of data to shuffle when you only need to know if sd/hd. You can do `select(when(...).as("P"))` earlier then do `agg(sum($"P"))` after group.

Comment: Thanks Hitobat for the response. I have used spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 2500 and currently running the job to process a batch of records at a time and using a shell script to submit the job by changing the parameter values. It is making good progress, but still issues when i run for whole table. For the initial job, loading data was taking 5-6hrs, group another    
 7-8hrs for group by and then majority of time is in save. Last run with all data ran for 15hrs in save and eventually failed. I have also used these two spark.shuffle.io.retryWait 60s spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries 10  properties.

Comment: OK i can try with persist. I was hesitant to try because of the size of data. I will try DISK_2. Also, thanks for suggestion on pre-processing. P only contains sd and hd. I have placed most of the conditionals in select, but yes can try moving this logic as well there and just do aggregations of numbers at this stage. Thanks, i will try and get back.

Comment: @Hitobat: I made the changes, but it still the job does not runs if i am running on full table. However, i was able to process around 3TB of data until now by processing a range of records at a time and submitting jobs in batches. The job for the full table always errors out with 'shuffle missing 0'